# Is it possible to have 'inlay hints' in Sublimetext (currently build 4143)?

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, inlay-hints

I'm writing something in TypeScript (Deno) using VSCode and love the inlay hints. I would like to try using SublimeText again, but I don't want to lose the inlay hints.

It's possible in IntelliJ, VSCode. Is it not possible in ST?

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/inlay-hints/54957/10

I followed the link that I pasted, followed the link where it says that something is standardised. Installed several packages, but no luck yet

Answer (score 1):

As rwols said in the link you posted, inlay hints can now be enabled in the main LSP settings. Select **`Preferences → Package Settings → LSP → Settings`** and scroll down the left side a little ways to find

```json
"show_inlay_hints": false,
```

Copy this over to the right side (the User settings), change `false` to `true`, save the file, and you should be all set. You may need to either restart your LSP servers or Sublime itself in order for it to be fully activated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried doing that, but unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: Which other packages do you have installed? Have you seen any evidence that LSP or one of its servers is working, such as a message on the bottom bar? Have you configured `LSP` itself or any of its sub-packages in any way? If you have, can you please edit your question and put the settings in there?

Comment: There is a [`LSP-Deno`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-Deno) package available - have you installed, configured, and run it?

Comment: I did install LSP and LSP-Deno and they seem to be working. I added the setting, made a project, enabled it in the project, enabled it globally, but it still doesn't work for me

Comment: At this point, you should probably head over to the [Sublime Discord Channel](https://discord.gg/TZ5WN8t) and ask in #LSP. The main devs for the LSP project hang out there, so you can get help right from the source.